# Spring integration problems: "Failed to read artifact description"

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-integration

I'm learnig using Spring integraions and i'm using a tutorial found on he web.
Making the exercises on Adapter, i'm using this basic pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.intertech.si</groupId>
    <artifactId>lab2-adapters</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring Integration Lab 2</name>
    <description>Lab 2 - using adapters</description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springframework.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <spring.integration.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
        <spring.integration.xml.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</spring.integration.xml.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-stream</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

Following tutorial's instructions, i need to add this depencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

but when i do this and i try to save file, i take many error on console log:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:jar:4.0.0.RELEASE
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:530)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1351)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:pom:4.0.0.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:pom:4.0.0.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Errore temporaneo nella risoluzione del nome
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:pom:4.0.0.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:pom:4.0.0.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Errore temporaneo nella risoluzione del nome
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 36 more
    pom.xml /lab2-adapters-starter  line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
```

his problems is specific of the last depency added, because if i try to delete this and save file, i have no error.

What could be the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with downloading the file. I dont know why but Maven cant solve this on its own. Got to your local repository cache, if you didn't change it it is at: [USER-DIR].m2\repository, and delete "org\springframework\integration".

Answer (score 0):

This pom.xml file is working fine on my PC environment. But I don't had any other old `spring integration jar` in my local m2 repository. So, according to your error message:

> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException:
>   Failure to transfer
>   org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:pom:4.0.0.RELEASE
>   **from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository,** resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file:pom:4.0.0.RELEASE
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   repo.maven.apache.org: Errore temporaneo nella risoluzione del nome

Did you notice that "from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 **was cached in the local repository**" message in your message.?

Perhaps, your previous version `spring integration jar` in your local repository are conflict with new `spring integration jar.`

**1) First way (I'm sure for that)** 
I think you need to delete the folder `$HOME/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration`

After that, rebuild and update the **maven** by using `mvn` command or by Eclipse.

**2) Second way (I'm not sure for that)** 
You don't need to delete any old jar. You just need to do force update to your repository by using `mvn` command or by Eclipse.